# Android: How to do a slide view/layout

Tags: android, animation, layout, view, gesture

I want to develope a slide view. It will be hide on bottom and when user drags the view, it will be visible.

Does anyone know some example with this funcionality?

In this application you can see an example:

[image]

[image]

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You could easily do this with a fragment. Create button that holds your "Charts" call to action. When the button is clicked, show the fragment.

You could probably also do that with a view that remain offscreen or even hidden and use animation to bring it in.